# Xpath3 expression in mulesoft to fetch all node names with particular attributes in order that they appear

Tags: xslt, mule

I have the below XML structure and I need to retrieve all node names that have attributes isAdded or isUpdated = 1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<peci:Effective_Change xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci" peci:Sequence="0">
    <peci:Derived_Event_Code>DTA</peci:Derived_Event_Code>
    <peci:Effective_Moment>01.11.2020</peci:Effective_Moment>
    <peci:Entry_Moment>23.11.2020</peci:Entry_Moment>
    <peci:Worker_Status>
        <peci:Status>Active</peci:Status>
        <peci:Active>1</peci:Active>
    </peci:Worker_Status>
    <peci:Position peci:isAdded="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Location_ID>US</peci:Location_ID>
        </peci:Business_Site>
        <peci:Position_End_Date peci:isAdded="1">01.11.2020</peci:Position_End_Date>
    </peci:Position>
    <peci:Position peci:isUpdated="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Location_ID>US</peci:Location_ID>
        </peci:Business_Site>
        <peci:Position_End_Date peci:isAdded="1">01.11.2020</peci:Position_End_Date>
    </peci:Position>
    <peci:Compensation peci:isUpdated="1">
        <peci:Position_ID>P0000</peci:Position_ID>
        <peci:Primary_Job>1</peci:Primary_Job>
        <peci:Business_Site>
            <peci:Country>US</peci:Country>
        </peci:Business_Site>
    </peci:Compensation>
</peci:Effective_Change>
```

The xpath that I have working is (which I tested on xpath testing website)

```
/*/*[@peci:isAdded = 1 or @peci:isUpdated = 1]/(local-name() || ' ' || local-name(@*))
```

This gives me the correct output. But I need help in implementing this in Mule 3.9. I tried to put this in expression and variable, but I am getting only the first nodename as output Positon isAdded. can someone guide me how I can achieve this mulesoft?

The output I am looking for is a list like below

```
Positon isAdded
Positon isUpdated
Compensation isUpdated
```

Can someone help?

I was able to achieve what I was looking for using XSLT. Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"  xmlns:peci="urn:com.workday/peci">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <ChangeArray>
        <xsl:for-each select="*/*[@peci:isAdded = 1 or @peci:isUpdated = 1]">
<ArrayOfstringVariable>
<name><xsl:value-of select="concat(local-name(),local-name(@*))"/></name>
</ArrayOfstringVariable>
        </xsl:for-each>
</ChangeArray>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You can use "XSLT" transformer in Mule to parse through

Comment: I never worked with XSLT....Can you help me on the XSLT transformation?

Comment: Thanks Star for the suggestion. I was able to achieve it using XSLT.

Comment: That's great you got it !!!